# Merging excel cells using office.js

Tags: javascript, office-js, excel-addins

I am trying to merge some cells using the Office.js API as stated in the question. I created a new web add in project using visual studio. I kept the generated project as is, and add a button with a click handler to merge the cells here is the code of the event handler.

```
function mergingCells() {
   Excel.run(function (ctx) {
   var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
   var range = sheet.getRange('A1:D2');
   range.merge(false);
   return ctx.sync().then(function () {
   showNotification('Merging done',
   'Merged range is ' + range.address);
   });
   }).catch(errorHandler);
}
```

the error that I get is : [image: error]

the expected result : [image: The expected result]

Comment: Could you post a complete code snippet (might I suggest doing so with [ScriptLab](https://aka.ms/scriptlab))?  Do you have appropriate error handling to bubble up any issues?  (Also, it seems strange that you're setting values on B3:D5, relative to the original range -- could you draw a picture of what you expect the result to look like?)

Comment: I used visual studio template as is, I did not change anything. I just add a button in the html and a click event handler in the Home.js (listed in the edited question).

Comment: Here is the script lab snippet : https://pastebin.com/aV4xTgeB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in your code in terms of not loading the range address in the `.then`.  But if I remove the `range.address`, or call `range.load("address")` before the sync, the code does work.

One thing I'm wondering:  what version of Office are you using?  If you are using Office 2016 RTM (not subscription-based Office 365), the merge method might just not be available (it's only part of `ExcelApi 1.2`, not `ExcelApi 1.1` that shipped with RTM).

You can see what API set a particular API belongs to in the IntelliSense:

[image: IntelliSense]

See https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/office-versions for more info on the Office version/flavors.

See https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/office-js-versioning for more info on Office JS versioning and requirement sets.

The RTM version of Office 2016 unfortunately did not differentiate between API not available and some of the other errors; so they both come across as `InvalidArgument` (but not for versions thereafter).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. It's clear to me now, the RTM version that I have of office 2016 is no longer good for the office.js add-in, I need to go to office 365.